# Initialize function to run once only

Tags: php, laravel

I'm inside a Laravel controller. I only want the `init()` method to fire *once*. What actually happens is, it fires every time I run the controller/methods via a browser?

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
    static $init_called = false;
    if(!$init_called){
        $init_called = true;
        $this->init();
    }
 }

 public function init()
 {
  // initialize code here, execute 'once' only
 }

 public function routeOne(){}

 public function routeTwo(){}
}
```

Comment: Side note: Its will be better check `init_called` in `init` function

Comment: The same behavior occurs if I do the check within the `init()` function.

Comment: I’m a little confused, but I haven’t had much coffee yet. You say “once” but then say every time you hit the controller, which to me is at least one definition of once. That static guard should work once per request. Unless you mean once in the lifetime of the code? Also, init should probably be private, too

Comment: Once, in the code lifetime, yes, that's what I'm getting at. To persist data to db, once only

Comment: That honestly sounds like something I’d do in setup code outside of my controller. But otherwise I’d use a really primitive lock, like drop a file at a known location. If it exists, it was run. But you’d probably have to drop two files, one for “I’m working” which means all other requests must block or throw until the work is done, and another for “I’m done”. The former can be done with [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html) and the latter just a normal file.

Comment: ``Persistence storage`` needs to be used to store a kind of flag that the init was called once.

Comment: Laravel migrations are a one-time initialization that might fit your use-case. They don't have to be database-related changes. Create a migration and call `php artisan migrate` once: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations

Comment: I'm aware of migrations, thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to store a value on session or on database. This value allow you to know if the function has already been called.
Then check the value at the top of the method every time it's is fired.
if it's true you can proceed to the normal instructions else you exit the function.

Comment: I'm not sure it will be possible without sessions or persistence because your application need to know if the method has already been fired or not. I don't know routeOne() method may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Since Http is a stateless protocol I'm probably attempting something outside of the realms of possibility. As a workaround, I used the following:-

```
// Call this route once only
Route::get('/init', [MyController::class, 'init'])->name('initialize');


class MyController extends Controller
{
 public function init()
 {
   MyModel::persistData();
 }
}


class MyModel extends Model
{
  private $data;

  public static function persistData()
  {
    $data = ['some data'];
    MyModel::insert($data);
  }
}
```